# COUNT within CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, case

Does anyone know why this gives an error near "FROM": syntax error?

```
SELECT voetbal_team_id_a,
CASE
    WHEN (COUNT(omschrijving) FROM gebeurtenis WHERE wedstrijd.voetbal_team_id_a = gebeurtenis.voetbal_team_id AND gebeurtenis.omschrijving = 'goal' AND wedstrijd.wedstrijd_id = gebeurtenis.wedstrijd_id) > 
         (COUNT(omschrijving) FROM gebeurtenis WHERE wedstrijd.voetbal_team_id_b = gebeurtenis.voetbal_team_id AND gebeurtenis.omschrijving = 'goal' AND wedstrijd.wedstrijd_id = gebeurtenis.wedstrijd_id) THEN 3
    ELSE 0
END AS wins
FROM wedstrijd

INNER JOIN gebeurtenis
ON wedstrijd.wedstrijd_id = gebeurtenis.wedstrijd_id
```

I want to create this:

[image: example]

But I'm not sure how CASE's work when u use an COUNT.

---

The COUNT itself should work, this is another query of mine:

```
SELECT wedstrijd.wedstrijd_id,
        (SELECT COUNT(omschrijving) FROM gebeurtenis WHERE wedstrijd.voetbal_team_id_a = gebeurtenis.voetbal_team_id AND gebeurtenis.omschrijving = 'goal' AND wedstrijd_id = wedstrijd.wedstrijd_id) AS Goals_A,
        (SELECT COUNT(omschrijving) FROM gebeurtenis WHERE wedstrijd.voetbal_team_id_b = gebeurtenis.voetbal_team_id AND gebeurtenis.omschrijving = 'goal' AND wedstrijd_id = wedstrijd.wedstrijd_id) AS Goals_B
FROM gebeurtenis
INNER JOIN wedstrijd
ON gebeurtenis.wedstrijd_id = wedstrijd.wedstrijd_id
GROUP BY wedstrijd.wedstrijd_id
```

This gives the following:

[image]

Comment: Please post the initial task, not the errorneous solution. Post CREATE TABLE for tables, INSERT INTO for some sample data, desired output for this sample data, and explainations. And none photos/pictures ! formatted text available for copying only.

Comment: *this is another query of mine* It is too over-engineered, and must be simplified, with excluding subqueries at all.

Comment: This question is just totally unclear.  The initial query has two columns, yet the intention is to create a table with four columns.  The names of the two columns have no relationship to the names of the four columns.  I'm baffled.

Comment: Generally you would put SUM() around a CASE statement like the one shown in the image to count the 1's.  Only need to do it this way if you have other fields to also return like a count() of matches so you can't exclude all losses in the WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

`case ... from`  is not valid SQL.

You can do what you want with `union all` and aggregation:

```
select team, sum(win) win
from (
    select hometeam teamp, (homescore > awayscore) win from matches
    union all select awayteam, (homescore < awayscore) from matches
) t
group by team
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create this

```sql
SELECT hometeam AS team, homescore > awayscore AS wins
FROM matches
```

will give the shown result. CASE not needed at all.